# Get executed SQL from nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using nHibernate ICriteria to execute a query, and I would like to be able to get the SQL that was executed after the statement runs. So for example I have something like this.

```
ISession session = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession();
DetachedCriteria query = BuildCriteria(); // Goes away and constructs the ICriteria
var result = query.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List<object>()

// somehow here get the sql that was just run
string sql = query.GetSqlSomehow();
```

I know I can log it and see the sql in the log, but I want to get it immediately after executing the statement so I can display the SQL to the user (even if it doesn't look nice).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704462/how-can-i-have-nhibernate-only-generate-the-sql-without-executing-it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can attach an `IInterceptor` to your NH `ISession`, then use the `OnPrepareStatement()` method to trap [(even modify](http://www.davesquared.net/2008/08/modifying-sql-generated-by-nhibernate.html)) the SQL.

Comment: I like this method, and iv implemented the Interception logic and currently intercept the SaveOrUpdate method, but where do i go from there to catch the sql statement? Invocation.Request...?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Log4Net configuration to capture the SQL being used. 
To start you'd need to create a custom appender such as this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Core;

public class NHibernateQueryAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
        private static List<string> s_queries = new List<string>();
    private static int s_queryCount = 0;

    public static IList<string> CurrentQueries
    {
           get { return s_queries.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public static int CurrentQueryCount
    {
        get { return s_queryCount; }
    }

    public static void Reset()
    {
        s_queryCount = 0;
        s_queries.Clear();
    }

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        s_queries.Add(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
        s_queryCount++;
    }
}
```

---

Then configure log4net like so:

```
<log4net>
    <...other config...>

    <appender name="nhquerycheck" type="NHibernateExecutor.Loggers.NHibernateQueryAppender, NHibernateExecutor" />

    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="nhquerycheck" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

The above class can then be queried at runtime such as to display the sql output to screen

---

Edit: for some reason post didn't come out correctly, so found example on web
http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/how-to-configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the "NHibernate Profiler" tool for this.  It's well worth the price since it also does a good job analyzing your usage of NHibernate and noticing potential problems.

Comment: I realise NHibernate Profiler is good at what it does, but if you read the question again I am not after a profiler or looking for potential problems.

Comment: Ahhh so you need to see the SQL at runtime? I was thinking you just wanted to see the actual SQL which is what I use NHProf for most of the time.