# Logging NHibernate SQL queries

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Is there a way to access the full SQL query, including the values, inside my code?

I am able to log SQL queries using log4net:

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NHibernateSQLFileLog"/>
</logger>
```

However, I would like to find a way to log SQL queries from the code also.  This way I will log the specific SQL query that causes an exception in my try/catch statement.

Right now I have to data-mine the SQLFileLog to find the query that caused the exception when an exception occurs and it is not efficient.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264132/get-executed-sql-from-nhibernate

Answer (score 11):

you can use an interceptor to do this:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor {
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql) {
        
        Debug.WriteLine(sql);

        return sql;
    }
}
```

See [Nhibernate Docs (webarchive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20101111183545/http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-interceptors) for the different ways to register it with nhibernate.

Comment: is possible to capture parameters value ?

Comment: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-interceptors not found, any sample using `LoggingInterceptor ` ?

Answer (score 7):

You can override driver:

```
public class LoggerSqlClientDriver:SqlClientDriver, IEmbeddedBatcherFactoryProvider
{      
    public override void AdjustCommand(IDbCommand command)
    {
        //log here
        base.AdjustCommand(command);
    }

    //protected override void OnBeforePrepare(IDbCommand command)
    //{
    //    //log here
    //    base.OnBeforePrepare(command);
    //}
}
```

And then use it in configuration:

```
var config = Fluently.Configure().
            Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.Driver<LoggerSqlClientDriver>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Either use sql profiler or have a look at nhprof at http://nhprof.com/

Both will let you see sql output.

Also set the show_sql property in hibernate config file

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Comment: I use it in code `configuration = new Cfg.Configuration(); configuration.SetProperty(Cfg.Environment.ShowSql, "true"); _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` but not working

Answer (score 1):

Use a log4net appender with specific target (afair it supports being toggled on/off) or just extend it and toggle it within your try-catch-finally-off.