# How to capture SQL statements of NHibernate with resharper and xunit 2

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate, resharper, xunit

I´m trying to display the sql statements of nhibernate from my XUnit 2.x unittests in the Resharper Output of the Unit Test Sessions, but it does log the sql statements.

With **MSpec Tests** there is no issue and the sql statements are shown. With **XUnit 1.x** I think the sql statements were also logged.

I have configured NHibernate via property `show_sql`

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

There was [a change](https://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output.html) in XUnit 2 how output is captured, but I not sure how to combine this with NHibernate to log the sql statements.

So has anyone a solution for this? I´m trying to avoid log4net integration in my unittests only to log these statements.

XUnit 2.1,
NHibernate 4.0,
ReSharper 2016.3.1,
Visual Studio 2013

Comment: It might be possible with xUnit's `ITestOutputHelper` and an interceptor as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2874025/1162077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @David Osborne´s comment I use an `EmptyInterceptor` to capture the SQL statements of NHibernate and write them to the `ITestOutputHelper` provided by the XUnit framework.

```
public class XUnitSqlCaptureInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public XUnitSqlCaptureInterceptor(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.Output = output;
    }

    public ITestOutputHelper Output { get; set; }

    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        this.Output.WriteLine(sql.ToString());

        return sql;
    }
}
```

The usage is as follows:

```
[Fact]
public void MyUnitTestWithSQL()
{
    using (var session = factory.OpenSession(new XUnitSqlCaptureInterceptor(this.output)))
    {
        using (var transcation = session.BeginTransaction())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where to get to the factory?

Comment: and this.output?